# Keyboard is messing up my animations of views in a controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiviewanimation

i'm trying to create a simple drawing app.. that has a set of controls that can be hidden or shown by the press of a UIButton which is transparent. The problem is with the keyboard. every time the keyboard shows up, wether its to type the title or create text box.. the animations reset and undo by themselves... i have no clue why thats happening.

Please help me... the code to move the controls up and back down is posted here:-

```
- (void) hideShowTopBarAnimated
{
    if(self.isTopBarHidden == NO)
    {
        self.hideShowButtonPointingUp.alpha = 0.0;
        [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.3
                                       delay:0.0
                                     options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                                  animations:^(void){
                                      CGPoint center;
                                      center = self.topBarImage.center;
                                      center.y -= 80;
                                      self.topBarImage.center = center;

                                      center = self.titleBar.center;
                                      center.y -= 80;
                                      self.titleBar.center = center;

                                      center = self.backgroundPicker.center;
                                      center.y -= 80;
                                      self.backgroundPicker.center = center;

                                      center = self.writingPicker.center;
                                      center.y -= 80;
                                      self.writingPicker.center = center;

                                      center = self.backgroundLabel.center;
                                  center.y -= 80;
                                  self.backgroundLabel.center = center;

                                  center = self.penLabel.center;
                                  center.y -= 80;
                                  self.penLabel.center = center;

                                  center = self.writeDrawToggle.center;
                                  center.y -= 80;
                                  self.writeDrawToggle.center = center;

                                  center = self.invisibleBackgroundButton.center;
                                  center.y -= 80;
                                  self.invisibleBackgroundButton.center = center;

                                  center = self.invisibleShowHideUIButton.center;
                                  center.y -= 80;
                                  self.invisibleShowHideUIButton.center = center;

                              }
                              completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                  self.hideShowButtonPointingDown.alpha = 1.0;

                              }];


    self.isTopBarHidden = YES;
}
else if(self.isTopBarHidden == YES)
{
    self.hideShowButtonPointingDown.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.3
                                   delay:0.0
                                 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                              animations:^(void){
                                  CGPoint center;
                                  center = self.topBarImage.center;
                                  center.y += 80;
                                  self.topBarImage.center = center;

                                  center = self.titleBar.center;
                                  center.y += 80;
                                  self.titleBar.center = center;

                                  center = self.backgroundPicker.center;
                                  center.y += 80;
                                  self.backgroundPicker.center = center;

                                  center = self.writingPicker.center;
                                  center.y += 80;
                                  self.writingPicker.center = center;

                                  center = self.backgroundLabel.center;
                                  center.y += 80;
                                  self.backgroundLabel.center = center;

                                  center = self.penLabel.center;
                                  center.y += 80;
                                  self.penLabel.center = center;

                                  center = self.writeDrawToggle.center;
                                  center.y += 80;
                                  self.writeDrawToggle.center = center;

                                  center = self.invisibleBackgroundButton.center;
                                  center.y += 80;
                                  self.invisibleBackgroundButton.center = center;

                                  center = self.invisibleShowHideUIButton.center;
                                  center.y += 80;
                                  self.invisibleShowHideUIButton.center = center;

                              }
                              completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                  self.hideShowButtonPointingUp.alpha = 1.0;
                              }];

    self.isTopBarHidden = NO;
}
}
```

Comment: Is there reason you dont just put all your controls on a single `UIView` and just animate the `UIView` rather than all of the separate components? You can set its `UIColour` to clear.  Can you clarify what "animations reset and undo" means

Comment: I agree. The first step to figuring this out will be to put all the control in a single view and animate that view. That will make your code much more smaller.

Comment: thanks for the advice. :) I'll implement the single view. Then i'll figure t out.